# High discrepancy between GA4 and Google Ads

Tags: google-analytics, google-search

In January 2024, Google Ads (paid search) recorded 151k clicks, whereas GA4 reported only 44k new users (representing just 29%).

What could be the cause for this discrepancy between Google products? Could this be due to the attribution models used in both platforms? Or I'm I using the wrong metrics to compare.

Thanks!